# Removing constraint from a model in cplex c++ concert tech

Tags: c++, cplex

I have one constraint set

```
for(int t = 0; t < NbPeriods; t++){
    for (int j =0; j < NbLocations; j++){
        IloExpr Ct1(env);
        for(int u = 0; u < t; u++){
            Ct1 += Fortified[u][j];
        }
        model.add(Interdicted[t][j] <= 1 - Ct1); 
    } 
}​
```

after some modification I have to remove this constraint set from the model. `model.remove()` is not working. How can I do it using `IloRangeArray protection(env)` in this case.

Comment: Why do you need the third loop if `Fortified[t][j]` doesn't depend on `u`? Would it be easier to use `t*Fortified[t][j]`? or it's mistake.

Comment: It's a mistake.  It's the summation upto that period. Now I have changed it . please help me for answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to define you constraints through `IloConstraint` before adding to the model and save in a container (e.g.,`IloConstraintArray`). Cplex removes a constraint from the model by its name not the expression. In your case,

```
IloConstraintArray cons_array(env);
for(int t = 0; t < NbPeriods; t++){
    for (int j =0; j < NbLocations; j++){
        IloExpr Ct1(env);
        for(int u = 0; u < t; u++){
            Ct1 += Fortified[u][j];
        }
        IloConstraint cons = Interdicted[t][j] <= 1 - Ct1;
        model.add(cons); 
        cons_array.add(cons);
    } 
}​
```

to remove

```
for (int i = 0; i < NbPeriods*NbLocations; i++)
     model.remove( cons_array[i] );
```

You can also use `cplex.exportModel("model.lp")` to export you model to a file after adding and after removing constraints and check if constrains are removed

Comment: Thanks a lot sir for your help