# MIP: Fixing a partial solution vector in CPLEX (C++)

Tags: c++, optimization, linear-programming, cplex, mixed-integer-programming

I am implementing a matheuristic with CPLEX in C++, where I start the same MIP multiple times with different partial solution vectors provided.

However, I do not only want to provide a starting solution, I want the variables in the partial solution vector to be seen as fixed during the whole optimization procedure (the reason is, to always explore different parts of the search space in a controlled manner).

Searching through the documentation of CPLEX and here, I can't really find a fitting function call providing the functionality I am looking for and would really appreciate tipps how to approach this problem in a good and efficient way.

There is one solution-approach I can think of, which is fixing the variables through adding constraints such as y == 4 to the model and after solving the resulting sub-MIP, removing the constraint from the model (as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35307719/removing-constraint-from-a-model-in-cplex-c-concert-tech)). However, are there better options to achieve this? And are there possibilities to exploit the preprocessing information gained by solving one MIP with fixed partial solution vector a for afterwards solving the same MIP with a different fixed partial solution vector b? After all, the core model did not change.

Regarding warm-starting CPLEX with a partial solution, I found the Level 3 [CPX_MIPSTART_SOLVEMIP](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/CPLEX/UsrMan/topics/discr_optim/mip/para/49_mipStarts.html) effort level with the description:

> solves a subMIP. You must specify the value of at least one discrete
> variable at this effort level

But am I interpreting this correctly, that this means it tries to construct a starting solution by solving the sub-MIP and then proceed with the whole optimization problem possible changing variables given in the starting solution, whereas I am interested in only solving the subMIP.

Thank you!

Comment: Fixing is usually done by setting the lower and upper bound of a variable.

Comment: Ah, so I basically do a [setMin()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloIntVar.html#method_setMin) and [setMax()](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refcppcplex/html/classes/IloIntVar.html#method_setMax) to the same value and change the bounds for each problem.

Comment: Yes. Depending on the model, you may need to save the original bounds so when you want to unfix a variable you can restore the original bounds.

Comment: Just to add that I have done this on several real-world problems and it works quite well (in some problems it works *very* well). In (an older version of?) the Concert C++ libraries, we were able to build the main model in one IloModel object and add the fixing constraints in another IloModel and then solve the resulting combined model created by adding the two models together. That way we didn't have to repeat the model building process and it simplified the adding/removing of the fixing constraints.

Comment: @TimChippingtonDerrick Very interesting, thank you for that tip! Just to interpret you correctly, you did not change the lower/upper bounds of the variables but explicitly added fixing constraints in your separate IloModel? Furthermore, in that context, did you also find a way, to save some preprocessing and/or root node processing time or did you (and CPLEX) repeat all the preprocessing and root node proecessing steps even though you only fixed "a few" different variables?

Comment: We were exploring 'Very Large Neighbourhood Search' (VLNS) ideas, so we were fixing the values of maybe 98% or 99% of the variables, just leaving a (large) neighbourhood for the solver to explore. In that case the presolve is very effective at using that large number of fixed values and so runs quite quickly. We also found that using the previous solution values as a warm-start for the remaining un-fixed values was useful, because we were not changing the overall problem, just un-fixing and re-solving small parts of the problem in the context of the rest of the (fixed) solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Just curious, did your warm-start provide a feasible or infeasible solution? 

I am also exploring a VLNS idea, I do not know how much values I will fix, as I am still in the implementation process, but probably only a small percentage (this is inherent to the respective matheuristic) and the solver is used for a heuristic search process through the (very) large neighbourhood. I also will warm-start the model and I have two warm-starting approaches in my head, one more complex which will result in a feasible solution, and an easy one which will probably be infeasible